# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, merge, delta-lake

I am new to PySpark and i am trying to merge a dataframe to the one present in Delta location using the merge function.

```
DEV_Delta.alias("t").merge(df_from_pbl.alias("s"),condition_dev)\
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()\
  .execute()
```

Both the dataframes have equal number of columns but when i run this particular command in my notebook i get the following error
`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'`

I couldnt find solutions for this particular task and hence raising a new question. Could you please help me figuring out this issue?

Thanks,
Afras Khan

Comment: How did you create `df_from_pbl` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an instance of the `DeltaTable` class, but you're passing the DataFrame instead.  For this you need to create it using the `DeltaTable.forPath` (pointing to a specific path) or `DeltaTable.forName` (for a named table), like this:

```py
DEV_Delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'some path')
DEV_Delta.alias("t").merge(df_from_pbl.alias("s"),condition_dev)\
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()\
  .execute()
```

If you have data as DataFrame only, you need to write them first.

See [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge) for more details.

Comment: Thank You so much! This worked. However, after the merge i am not able to find the new records in target directory. I am passing few rows in "df_from_pbl" which are supposed to get inserted. The Merge gets executed but those new rows are not inserted in target file

Comment: check condition. Also, check history of the table - it will say how many are inserted/updated/deleted